# Query pandas df on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas df.

```
columns = ['question_id', 'answer', 'is_correct']
data = [['1','hello','1.0'],
       ['1','hello', '1.0'],
       ['1','hello', '1.0'],
        ['2', 'dog', '0.0'],
        ['2', 'cat', '1.0'],
        ['2', 'dog', '0.0'],
        ['2', 'the answer is cat', '1.0'],
        ['3', 'Milan', '1.0'],
        ['3', 'Paris', '0.0'],
        ['3', 'The capital is Paris', '0.0'],
        ['3', 'MILAN', '1.0'],
        ['4', 'The capital is Paris', '1.0'],
        ['4', 'London', '0.0'],
        ['4', 'Paris', '1.0'],
        ['4', 'paris', '1.0'],
        ['5', 'lol', '0.0'],
        ['5', 'rofl', '0.0'],
        ['6', '5.5', '1.0'],
        ['6', '5.2', '0.0']]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)
df
```

I want to return a list of lists. An inner list should contain exactly two **correct** (is_correct = 1.0) answers (a1 and a2) from the same question. One inner list per question_id. The other answers within a question_id can simply be ignored.

**Edge cases:**

1. All answers are correct -> then just take a duplicate. See question_id = 1
2. No answer is correct -> then skip this question. E.g. output None. See question_id = 5
3. Only one answer is correct -> then skip this question. E.g. output None. See question_id = 5

Example:

```
[['Paris', 'The capital is Paris'], ['MILAN', 'milano'],...]
```

My current approach outputs the same for a1 and a2. What am I doing wrong?

```
# This takes around 1min on cpu
def filter(grp):
    is_correct = grp['is_correct'] == 1.0
    if is_correct.any():
        sample = grp.sample()
        a1 = grp['answer'][is_correct].iloc[0]
        a2 = grp['answer'][is_correct].iloc[0]
        n = 6
        _ = 0
        # I will compare a1 and a2 6 times to see if they are the same
        # and if they are the same grap another one for a2... probably not smart
        while _ < n:
          if a1.index == a2.index:
            a2 = grp['answer'][is_correct].iloc[0]
          _ +=1
        return [a1, a2]

data = df.groupby('question_id').apply(filter).to_list()
# Drop None values
data_clean = [x for x in data if x is not None and x[1] is not None]
data_clean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
# get groups with at least one correct answer
res = df[df['is_correct'].astype(float).gt(0)].groupby('question_id')['answer'].agg(lambda x: x.head(2).to_list()).to_list()

# filter out groups with only one element
out = [l for l in res if len(l) > 1]
print(out)
```

**Output**

```
[['hello', 'hello'], ['cat', 'the answer is cat'], ['Milan', 'MILAN'], ['The capital is Paris', 'Paris']]
```

Comment: I am just letting you know that you made my day with it. Thank you.

Comment: @Exa glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

If you need your results shuffled as well:

```py
def filter(g): 
    answers = g.loc[g.is_correct == 1.0, 'answer'] 
    # Presumably we want a random shuffle of the answers
    answers = list(answers.sample(frac=1)) 
    # Require at least one answer 
    if len(answers) == 0: 
        return None 
    # Duplicate if only one answer 
    elif len(answers) == 1: 
        answers = answers*2 
    return answers[:2] # answers is a list already, so can index

list(df.groupby('question_id').apply(filter))
```

Output:

```py
[['hello', 'hello'],
 ['cat', 'the answer is cat'],
 ['MILAN', 'Milan'],
 ['paris', 'Paris'],
 None,
 ['5.5', '5.5']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very good structure, makes it easier for me to understand it! Somehow, it also outputs the question_id for me including the title question_id:  
question_id
1                   ['hello', 'hello'] 
2                   ['cat', 'the answer is cat']
I am using google colab, not sure if that's the reason.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've added `to_list()` to the end of the `groupby` line: does this give the output you're expecting?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Then I am getting the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_list'. However, I noticed that I am also getting the error with the dummy code and df I posted above. So, the problem is on my side and your code works.

Comment: Alternatively (depending on versions of pandas) you can do `list(df.groupby(...))`, which I believe is version independent. I've updated my answer accordingly!

Comment: One other note is that `is_correct` is actually a string in your example, so I need to do `df.is_correct = df.is_correct.astype(float)` before proceeding. This might also be version/OS dependent. Alternatively you can specify the types when calling `pd.DataFrame(...)`